# Mac Rcmdr isn't loading

Tags: r, macos

I'm a noob at r.  Please forgive what must be a common question, but I'm not even sure what to search for to find my answer.  I'm running r 3.3.3 on a Macbook running OS 10.11.6 (El Capitan).  I've installed r and RStudio.  I'm attempting to install rcmdr, but I get the following messages:

```
The downloaded binary packages are in

/var/folders/1x/153rlwbs2y16fy9vgglb9gxw0000gn/T//RtmpHOiWjy/downloaded_packages
> local({
+   old <- getOption("defaultPackages")
+   options(defaultPackages = c(old, "Rcmdr"))
+ })
> library("Rcmdr",         
lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library")
Loading required package: splines
Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
Loading required package: car
Loading required package: sandwich
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'Rcmdr', details:    
  call: structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj")
  error: [tcl] invalid command name "image".

In addition: Warning message:
In fun(libname, pkgname) : couldn't connect to display ":0"
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'Rcmdr'
  error: [tcl] invalid command name "image".

In addition: Warning message:
In fun(libname, pkgname) : couldn't connect to display ":0"
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'Rcmdr'
```

How do I fix this?  And how do I figure out how to answer these questions on my own in the future?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved installing XQuartz https://www.xquartz.org/.

When you go to execute, you first have to open XQuartz and then R console and write the command "library(Rcmdr)"